# Visual pictures of rotation and torsion

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, vector-spaces

In vector analysis / differential geometry we have rotation and torsion. The formalisms are certainly well known. But how could I best explain the geometric pictures and their difference (as a coach of an exercises group of bachelors who just started this topic)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a beautiful animation created by [Urs Hartl](http://www.math.uni-muenster.de/u/urs.hartl/) at Universität Münster:

   [image]
Urs created this in [Maple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maple_(software)). The [worksheet (.mw)](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=worksheet/documenting/WorksheetMode), which allows user-input 
of curves, is [here](http://www.math.uni-muenster.de/u/urs.hartl/gifs/CurvatureAndTorsionOfCurves_DE.mw).